# Snackbar vs Toast

Tags: android, toast, snackbar

I am new in android development and I am confused between Context and View.So, I just wanna know Why we pass view in Snackbar but context in Toast while we use both to show the notification/message.

Answer (score 4):

`Snackbar` traverses up the View tree until it decides where to be placed. It will then attach itself to the View tree. Thus, it needs a View attached to the view tree as a starting point.

`Toast` just displays a floating message on the screen.  It does not need to be attached to any view, so it does not need a View object.  It does, however, require some knowledge of the platform, so a `Context` is suitable.

Answer (score 3):

A `Toast` is just shown on top of whatever happens to be on the screen at the time. It is not connected in any way with what happens to be on the screen at the time. In fact, your `Toast` can be shown on top of another completely different application. `Toast` requires a `Context` because you can pass a resource ID as a parameter and Android will need to access your application's resources (via `Context`). Android also needs a `Context` because it ties your `Toast` to your application so that it can clean it up under certain circumstances.

A `Snackbar` is more tightly coupled to your application's UI. A `Snackbar` is a `View` which is tied to your application's view heirarchy. When you create a `Snackbar`, you pass a `View` as a parameter so that Android can scan the view heirarchy to find an appropriate location within the view heirarchy to create the `Snackbar`. If your view heirarchy contains a `CoordinatorLayout` the `Snackbar` gets additional behaviour (swipe to dismiss, moving a floating action button out of the way).  A `Snackbar` cannot be displayed if you have no UI, and a `Snackbar` cannot be displayed in another application's UI.